# I have an equation that I cannot solve, can anyone time how to get to $x=0.1225$?

Tags: exponential-function

How do I solve the following equation?:
$$
0.2 = 0.819 \exp(-11.5x)+0.0975 \exp(-70.1x)+0.0325 \exp(-179x)
$$
The result is supposed to be $x \approx 0.1225$

Comment: Most probably, there is no standard way for solving this type of question, by hand. If you want to know solution(s) *only*, you can use Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The huge negative exponents will make the last two terms on the right very small, so you can get a preliminary value by ignoring them.  We get $\ln \frac {0.2}{0.819}\approx -11.5x, x \approx 0.122588$  Now you can incorporate the other terms in a fixed point iteration 
$$0.2 = 0.819 \exp(-11.5x)+0.0975 \exp(-70.1x)+0.0325 \exp(-179x)\\
\frac {-1}{11.5}\log \left(\frac 1{0.819}\left(0.2-0.0975 \exp(-70.1x_i)0.0325 \exp(-179x_i)\right)\right)=x_{i+1}$$
The iteration will converge very rapidly